# Bit-wise operators and bit manipulation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I am new at using bit-wise operators and manipulating bits and I was wondering if someone knows some techniques or something that will help me to learn to do this properly.

Maybe some book or something that explains this well and how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend these resources:

- [Representation of Numbers](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html)
- [Binary Arithmetic](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/BinaryMath.html)
- [Low Level Bit Hacks You Absolutely Must Know](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/)

and absolute classic

- [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)